# insertion sort clarification Python

Tags: python, sorting

Hi I have a question about the if statement int he for j loop.  I understand that you swap the smaller value with the bigger value but  I don't understand why it is written as `waarde, rij[j] = rij[j], waarde`.  is the comma some sort of swapper in Python?

```
 def insertionsort(rij):            
     for i in range(len(rij)):         
         waarde = rij[i]               
         for j in range(0, i):        
             if waarde<rij[j]:        
                 waarde, rij[j] = rij[j], waarde   
         rij[i] = waarde
```

Comment: @Stefano  You beat me to it.  I was formatting to when I saw the output. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python,

```
a, b = b, a
```

effectively swaps the values `a` and `b`. More precisely, the name `a` will now reference the value that was previously referenced by `b` and vice versa.

This is called tuple packing/unpacking. The comma builds tuples; the swapping is done by the `=`.

What happens "behind the scenes" is this:

- The tuple `b, a` is evaluated. You can imagine the result of this evaluation to be stored in an unnamed temporary variable. Let's call that variable `temp`.
- The assignment operator `=` now causes `temp` to be assigned to the name(s) on the left side of the `=`. If there had been just one name on the left, as in `x = b, a`, then `x` would have been assigned the tuple `b, a`.
- Since there is more than one name on the left side, `temp` will be "unpacked" into these names in sequence.
- `a` will be assigned the value of `temp[0]` (which holds the value that `b` pointed to), and `b` will be assigned the value of `temp[1]`.

Note that the number of names on both sides must match:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> a, b = c, b, a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

But you can use the tuple packing operator `*` to tell Python to pack the remaining values into a single name:

```
>>> a, *b = c, b, a
>>> a
3
>>> b
[2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can assign multiple varialbes like this:

```
a, b = "A", "B"
```

This is saying: assign the first value on the right of the `=` to the first name on the left of the `=`, and assign the second value on the right of the `=` to the second name on the left of the `=`.

You can also do it with three or more vars:

```
a, b, c, d = "A", "B", "C", "D"
```

You can use this feature to swap the values of variables:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Now when you print `a` you get "B" and when you print `b` you get "A".